# How to use go tool compile?

Tags: go

Simple code [recursion and tails](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/09/recursion-and-tail-calls-in-go_26.html)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func TailRecursive(number int, product int) int {

    product = product + number

    if number == 1 {

        return product
    }

    return TailRecursive(number-1, product)
}

func main() {

    answer := TailRecursive(5, 0)
    fmt.Printf("Recursive: %d\n", answer)
}
```

When I try tool compile

```
go tool compile 6g -S ./g9.go > assembly.asm
```

I got this

```
 cat assembly.asm 
6g:0:0: open 6g: no such file or directory
```

My kernel architecture

```
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How to use go tool compile to get the proper assembly output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the 6g (it's now known as `compile`)

```
go tool compile -S ./g9.go > assembly.asm
```

Output

```
"".TailRecursive STEXT size=107 args=0x18 locals=0x20
    0x0000 00000 (g9.go:5)  TEXT    "".TailRecursive(SB), $32-24
    0x0000 00000 (g9.go:5)  MOVQ    (TLS), CX
    0x0009 00009 (g9.go:5)  CMPQ    SP, 16(CX)
    0x000d 00013 (g9.go:5)  JLS 100
    0x000f 00015 (g9.go:5)  SUBQ    $32, SP
    0x0013 00019 (g9.go:5)  MOVQ    BP, 24(SP)
    0x0018 00024 (g9.go:5)  LEAQ    24(SP), BP
    0x001d 00029 (g9.go:5)  FUNCDATA    $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (g9.go:5)  FUNCDATA    $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (g9.go:5)  FUNCDATA    $3, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (g9.go:7)  PCDATA  $2, $0
    0x001d 00029 (g9.go:7)  PCDATA  $0, $0
    0x001d 00029 (g9.go:7)  MOVQ    "".number+40(SP), AX
    0x0022 00034 (g9.go:7)  MOVQ    "".product+48(SP), CX
    0x0027 00039 (g9.go:7)  ADDQ    AX, CX
    0x002a 00042 (g9.go:9)  CMPQ    AX, $1
    0x002e 00046 (g9.go:9)  JNE 63
    0x0030 00048 (g9.go:11) MOVQ    CX, "".~r2+56(SP)
    0x0035 00053 (g9.go:11) MOVQ    24(SP), BP
    0x003a 00058 (g9.go:11) ADDQ    $32, SP
    0x003e 00062 (g9.go:11) RET
    ...
```